# Zend_Form isValid() using getPost() vs $_POST

Tags: zend-framework

I have been using this syntax for a while now because I thought there was some sort of advantage:

```
if ($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()))
```

...but is there really any advantage to calling `getPost()` versus simply calling `$_POST`:

```
if ($form->isValid($_POST))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does exactly the same. you can open up `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` and review the getPost() function yourself. it's returning $_POST without filtering.

Personally, I like to use Zend framework functions rather than global variables, because if something will get changed in the PHP language, the zend framework developers will take care of the changes.

For example, the POST variable was deprecated at some point (`$HTTP_POST_VARS`) and renamed to `$_POST`. so using the zend framework function might be a little safer for future PHP updates..

Comment: I'm a lot more likely to change my Zend Framework version than PHP version, so I don't know if it's really safer, but I see your point. Thanks for your answer.